# How do I place a single character from unicode in a LaTeX document?

Tags: unicode

I want to place a character from several, non-Latin, languages. I guess I can do this using unicode, but how do I do that? Specificaly, I want to place the Hebrew Aleph and the digit currently used in Arabic for 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to make sure you use a font which supports these characters.

Then, you could simply type the character or copy it from somewhere.

Otherwise, using XeTeX or LuaTeX, if you know the code, you can use `\char"<thecode>`, for example:

`\char"2135` will typeset an Hebrew aleph (ℵ), and `\char"0661` for an Arabic one (١).