# Getting unicode characters with TeXnicCenter

Tags: unicode, texniccenter

I would like to display some korean characters in the output of a tex file. I am using LaTeX with TeXnicCenter. I am envisioning something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{...}
\begin{document}
\displayutfcharacter{12345}
\end{document}
```

I am preparing some slides in beamer. Once again, I do *not* want to write any fancy characters directly into the input file. Just refer to their utf code.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26492/how-do-i-place-a-single-character-from-unicode-in-a-latex-document help?

Comment: Speravir: 1.0 Stable RC1, MikTeX 2.9. I am hesitating to migrate to an alpha version, and I do not want to directly input unicode. @TorbjørnT.: \char"00410 seems to be the solution (which corresponds to a capital A, according to the wiki site: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode ), however, it produces a a bunch of "bad character code" error during compilation. It does not seems to be a font issue.

Comment: Deleted my old comment. In the meantime TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta is published. You should really consider to test it: What I said, you can directly input Unicode characters.